# Liferay: Fix the Error in eclipse by using Liferay IDE and own project folder organization

Tags: eclipse, ide, liferay, liferay-ide

I want to use the Liferay IDE, but I don't want to put my portlets to `~/liferay-sdk/portlets/` folder. Is it possible? Currently I get the error in eclipse:

```
No Liferay Plugin SDK configured on project CMS-portlet
```

And the selection of Liferay SDK is empty.

[image]

When I copy this portlet to `~/liferay-sdk/portlets/` folder then all works fine. But this is no way for me, I don't want to put my projects to sdk-folder.

Comment: I don't think it will work that way. You have no choice.

Comment: Have you tried symlinking ~/liferay-sdk/portlets/ to the actual location of the portlet source? Something like `ln -s /path/to/actualsource ~/liferay-sdk/portlets/` ?

Comment: I too thought of suggesting that, but seeing that the screenshot posted looks like Windows 7, I stopped :)

Comment: ...but, you could give http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-symlinks-in-windows-vista/ a try!

Comment: What is the version of your Liferay Developer Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the workaround thats work for me. Simple disable the Liferay SDK validaton:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the current version of Liferay IDE depends on the ant script integration from the plugins sdk, thus the requirement to have the ant infrastructure available (this lives inside the SDK).

You may have more luck with maven projects, but they're not directly supported by Liferay IDE, however, you can use them with plain eclipse. Also, even if you go without maven, you can work with plain eclipse.

Comment: Thank you for the answear, I hope one of the next versions of Liferay IDE will solved it.